# How to change the default value of a file to another value?

Tags: php, file, input

I am creating a updating form, is there a code to change the default value "no file choose" to another value?

this is my code,

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $categoryinfo['image']; ?>" name="image">
```

I want to see $categoryinfo['image'] in the box, but now i am seeing "no file choosen". Is there a way to change it?

Comment: you can't programatically set the value of a `file` input. to allow this would be a major security vulnerability and potentially let anyone steal any file they want for which they know the path.

Comment: makes no sense thats the file a user is uploading

Comment: Nope. You can't set the default value of a file input. It would be a security risk if you could. Nothing then would be stopping me from making the file input hidden (or off screen or something like that) and setting it to some secret file on your computer then submitting that file to my server.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below will do exactly what you want.

```js
window.nameChanger = function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('filePick');
    if(btn.value == "")
    {
        fileLabel.innerHTML = "Choose a file"; //used for if someone picks a file - then presses again and cancels.
    }
    else
    {
        var fileName = btn.value.split('\\');
        fileLabel.innerHTML = fileName[fileName.length-1];
    }
};
```

```css
input[type=file]{
    width:100px;
    color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input  title="Choose Something" type='file' id="filePick" onchange="nameChanger()">
  <label id="fileLabel">Whatever You Want</label>
</div>
```

You will find that this snippet will do what you need